# non-main thread does not wait for delegate methods to finish

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am trying to use threads in my app to call web service and get data from

> connectionDidFinishLoading

delegate method, but non-main thread does not wait for delegate methods to finish.

here is code for thread :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                //Here your non-main thread.
                [self Login_WS];
                //sleep(10);

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //Here you returns to main thread.
                    //[MMProgressHUD updateProgress:1.f];
                    [MMProgressHUD dismissWithSuccess:@"done"];
                    DetailOfMenu *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
                    //[colorVC setColor:color];
                    UINavigationController *colorNavi1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail];
                    [self.qp_splitViewController setRightController:colorNavi1];

                    MenuTableView *colorVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"];
                    //[colorVC setColor:color];
                    UINavigationController *colorNavi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:colorVC];
                    [self.qp_splitViewController setLeftController:colorNavi];
                });
            });
```

and here is code for web service :

```
-(void)Login_WS{

    flag =1;

    NSString* ENC_UserName = [self ENC:Username.text];
    NSString* ENC_Password = [self ENC:Password.text];

    NSString *envelopeText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                              "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
                              "<soap12:Body>\n"
                              "<GetReportsNames xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                              "</GetReportsNames>\n"
                              "</soap12:Body>\n"
                              "</soap12:Envelope>\n",];

    //envelopeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:envelopeText, txt1.text];
    NSData *envelope = [envelopeText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSLog(@"URL in Call_WS in SplashScreen %@",Var.url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];


    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetReportsNames" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:envelope];
    [request setValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [envelope length]]forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // fire away
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection)
        responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    else
        NSLog(@"NSURLConnection initWithRequest: Failed to return a connection.");

}
```

note: it is working fine in non-threading mood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the UI part that is currently after you call `[self Login_WS];` when the web service call returns a response or a failure.

As the webservice call is also async the Login_WS method returns immediately after you create it, so your UI code will get called there. Instead implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol and update your UI in:

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

or:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly at what point in code you want to wait and what part you want to prevent for getting executed. You issue is of synchronization category where one thread has to wait till other part finishes work. For this you can use NSCondition. You will find good examples on google for this :-)